# Splitting Data from a Column into two Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data in a column called "Medication_Description". First I need to

then find out who that received Tylenol also received a second drug (Ibuprofen here).

I also only want the top two results for each MRN (i.e. patient). I only want data for the past year.

Later I will be plugging this into an SSRS report where I will determine the percentage of patients that received both drugs.

I've played with a couple different ways of getting this to work but can't get it working quite right.

The data in this table looks like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

As for desired results, I'd like to have something like this:

> Blockquote[image: Desired_Results]

For MRN 654321, no Ibuprofen was administered so it returns NULL (it could also return another drug name - doesn't matter too much. I just need to be able to count the results later to determine a percentage).

For MRN 246824, only one dose of Ibuprofen was administered so the second line is NULL.

Below is my latest attempt but (as you can see) Med1 and Med2 will always reflect the same exact data - how can I make Med1 reflect one medication and Med2 reflect a second?

```
SELECT [MRN], [Med1], [Med2], [Row_Num], [Department_Name], [Date]
FROM 
  ( SELECT [MRN], [Medication_Description] AS [Med1], [Medication_Description] AS [Med2],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MRN]
                              ORDER BY [Medication_Description] DESC
                             )
             AS [Row_Num],
             [Date],
             [Department_Name]
    FROM T_Med_Orders
    WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND getdate() 
    AND [Department_Name] LIKE 'ICU'
    --First Med Must Match "Tylenol" but 2nd should match any result...???
    AND Medication_Description LIKE '%Tylenol%'
  )
  tmp 
WHERE 
[Row_Num] <= 2 
AND Med1 LIKE '%Tylenol%'
--AND Med2 LIKE '%Ibuprofen%'
AND [DATE] BETWEEN dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND getdate()
ORDER BY [MRN]
```

Comment: Some sample data would be useful.

Comment: Like the other comment said, some sample data would be useful so we can get an idea of the format of [Medical_Description]. Still, another piece of advice would be to put your Medical_Description LIKE clause in parenthesis. Your query, and therefore the Execution Plan, is ambiguous. It can't tell if you mean ((Date BETWEEN .... AND Dept_Name .... AND Med_Desc LIKE Ibuf) OR (Med_Desc LIKE Tylenol)). You need to format it as (Med_Desc LIKE Ibuf OR Med_Desc LIKE Tylenol) using parenthesis.

Comment: `[Medication_Description] AS [Med1], [Medication_Description] AS [Med2],` That makes no sense. You use the SAME column for both aliases

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know the Med1/Med2 doesn't make sense. I added it so you could understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Sample data looks like this:
MRN Medication_Description Department_Name DATE
123456 TRANEXAMIC ACID 1,000 MG/10 ML EMERGENCY DEPT 2/28/2022
654321 OXYCODONE 5 MG TABLET ICU 2/28/2022
246826 IOPAMIDOL 76 % INTRAVENOUS SOLUTION SURGERY DEPT 9/3/2021

Comment: Edit the question and add the formatted sample data and desired results

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question and added sample data and desired results. I'm using SQL Server 2012 as the tag indicates.

Comment: Time to think about upgrading. 2012 has barely a month left of extended support.

Answer (score 1):

You have a solid start, but I think you're being too ambitious with your query. While there are ways to optimize the query, using Partitions may be overkill for the current requirements. What I ended up doing was to make two CTEs where each is filtered to the individual medicine being identified. I can LEFT JOIN those to the source table and filter it to only show results where the CTE values are NOT NULL. I can also apply the other DeptName and Date clauses, although I have not done so in my code snippet.

The main drawback is that this format would require more and more CTEs if you wanted to expand to include other medicines, swiftly reducing optimization further. But without knowing how MedicationDescription is formatted (or if it even has a standard format) I can't write that for you.

```
WITH Tylenol_CTE AS
  (SELECT *, 'Tylenol' AS [FilteredMedicine]
  FROM #Temp
  WHERE Medication_Description LIKE '%Tylenol%')
,Ibuprofen_CTE AS
  (SELECT *, 'Ibuprofen' AS [FilteredMedicine]
  FROM #Temp
  WHERE Medication_Description LIKE '%Ibuprofen%')
SELECT t.*
  , Tylenol_CTE.[FilteredMedicine] AS Med1
  , Ibuprofen_CTE.[FilteredMedicine] AS Med2
FROM #Temp t
LEFT JOIN Tylenol_CTE
  ON t.MRN = Tylenol_CTE.MRN
  AND t.Date = Tylenol_CTE.Date
LEFT JOIN Ibuprofen_CTE
  ON t.MRN = Ibuprofen_CTE.MRN
  AND t.Date = Ibuprofen_CTE.Date
WHERE Ibuprofen_CTE.Medication_Description IS NOT NULL
AND Tylenol_CTE.Medication_Description IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I made it the part of the clause of the LEFT JOIN. For a result to be returned the MRN has to be the same for the source query, Tylenol_CTE and Ibuprofen_CTE. If that's not how MRN is supposed to be used then you can take it out of the LEFT JOIN clauses (I thought it was an ID number for a registered nurse).